# VS2010 Upgrade Edition - is 'upgrading' from express ligitimate?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've read from a non reliable source that purchasing VS2010 Upgrade Edition (As opposed to full retail) is a valid licensing route when 'upgrading' from VS Express (free) - Can anyone confirm or refute this?

Thank you

Comment: I doubt it is permitted (MS would be pretty stupid to allow this, no?).

Comment: I recall VS2008 Express qualified as an upgrade. For that matter, Eclipse qualified too IIRC.

Comment: @Oded -- To me it seems like a smart move. They get more people to buy in and commit to Microsoft, and then make extra money off the people who don't realize practically anyone qualifies for upgrade pricing.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like this is [true](http://emea.microsoftstore.com/UK/en-GB/Microsoft/Visual-Studio-Professional-2010-Upgrade):

> **Before you buy**
>
> Eligible for upgrade with any previous
>   version of Visual Studio or any other
>   developer tool.
>
> Visual Studio 2010 Professional
>   includes a 12-month MSDN Essentials
>   subscription. MSDN Essentials gives
>   you access to core Microsoft
>   platforms: Windows 7 Ultimate, Windows
>   Server 2008 Enterprise R2, and
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Datacenter
>   R2.
>
> **Special information for trial users** 
>   If you're using a trial version of
>   Visual Studio Professional and you buy
>   the Visual Studio 2010 Professional
>   Upgrade, you can use the product key
>   you get on the receipt page to convert
>   your trial version to a full version.

This seems to say that you can upgrade from any competing product or any existing version of Visual Studio, even a trial one. It doesn't explicitly mention the Express edition, but you could always install the trial version and upgrade that instead.

Comment: Why would they do this, I mean just because you have gone through the small hassle of installing the express edition you get £200 off???

Comment: It looks like they've clarified this further (http://www.microsoftstore.com.au/shop/en-AU/Microsoft/Visual-Studio-Professional-2010-Upgrade): To qualify for upgrade pricing, you must be a licensed user of one of the following products: an earlier version of Microsoft Visual Studio, or any other developer tool (including free developer tools, such as Visual Studio Express Editions or Eclipse).

Answer (score 2):

I sell software and didn't want to violate the license agreement.  So, I chatted with a MS rep (and have the chat log), then called the licensing number and was told the same thing from both.  The upgrade license is valid from ***ANY*** prior version (including express).  I asked about express specifically and more than once and was told this was just fine.